# How to run some tasks in parallel, and others sequentially?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to run some CD/CI tasks in parallel (independent docker builds for instance), and some others sequentially (the registry upload of these images once they are built, for instance).

The [documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/07/29/the-basics-of-gitlab-ci/) gives an example of standalone tasks which are built in parallel by default:

```
test:
  script: cat file1.txt file2.txt | grep -q 'Hello world'

package:
  script: cat file1.txt file2.txt | gzip > packaged.gz
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - packaged.gz
```

They force the sequentiality of these tasks though the `stages` entry:

```
stages:
  - test
  - package
```

**How can I mix both?** To have, say, the tasks `build_one` and `build_two` run in parallel, and then (sequentially) `package`? Something along the lines of

```
stages:
  - build_one, build_two   # <-- these two run in parallel
  - package   # <-- this one runs only when both parallel tasks above completed successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each task can be assigned a stage in which to run, and stages run sequentially in the order they are defined. If multiple tasks are assigned to the same stage, they run in parallel during that stage.

Here's an example that fits your requirement. Both build tasks run at the same time, then the package task runs afterward:

```
before_script:
  - echo "do some runner environment prep"

stages:
  - build
  - package

build_task1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "do build1 stuff"

build_task2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "do build2 stuff"

package_task:
  stage: package
  script:
    - echo "do package stuff"
```

And here's a successful pipeline run using this above pipeline definition:

[image]

Comment: Thank you . It did not occur to me that the tasks are tagged with the stage they belong to (I was looking for exactly the opposite way to have it running)